# NOT REGISTERED ON NETWORK

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-8

I recently bought a used **Samsung S8** but it always tell me that **"NOT REGISTERED ON NETWORK"** I have at several times tried to clear data on Sim Toolkit, Reset Network Settings and Factory Reset but nothing at the end. when i contacted the person who sold me the same phone, he just went to blame me for upgrading it to android 9.0 which i do not think is true. someone again told me that it could have been blocked by the manufacturer. please anyone to help me with the possible solution

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to insert a working SIM card?

Comment: @Robert yes, i have tried several times

Comment: yes that's what it is saying **NOT REGISTERED ON NETWORK** but it keeps showing full network bars on the screen

Comment: @Robert check my edited post